# Not able to focus input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I'm trying to focus an input box that is inside an Antd tab whenever the user clicks this tab (i.e., whenever the input box is visible). I'm using the useImperativeHandle hook to achieve this.

**parent component**

```js
const Parent=()=>{
const threadRef=useRef()
() => {
  const onTabChange = activeKey => {
    if (activeKey === 1 && chatThreadRef.current) {
      chatThreadRef.current.focusInput()
    }
  }
  return (
    <Tabs
      items={[
        { label: 'tab 1', key: 0, children: <>tab 1</> },
        { label: 'tab 2', key: 1, children: <ChildComponent/> },
      ]}
      onChange={onTabChange}
    />
  )
}
}
```

**Child component**

```js
const ChildComponent = forwardRed((props,ref) => {
  const [focusableElements, setFocusableElements] = useState([])
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const messageInput = wrapperRef.current.querySelector('input')
    setFocusableElements(messageInput)
  }, [])

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focusInput: () => {
      console.log(focusableElements[0])
      focusableElements[0].value = '1'
      focusableElements[0].focus()
    },
  }))
  return (
    <div ref={wrapperRef}>
      <Input className="input" />
    </div>
  )
})
```

Whenever the focusInput is called the in the parent component      `console.log(focusableElements[0])` statement in the code prints the input element and i'm also able to set the value to the input but its not getting focussed.

Comment: you aren't passing the ref to ChildComponent (and you have a typo in `forwardRef`). Also why are you using a `ref` and then querying off of it? Just apply the ref to the actual element you want a reference to. You could also just apply the `autoFocus` prop to the Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed this by adding timeout like this

```
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focusInput: () => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
      focusableElements[0].value = '1'
      focusableElements[0].focus()
    },100)
    },
  }))
```

Comment: Using a timeout works, but is crude and feels laggy. A better solution is to call .focus() in a useEffect, as shown in another answer

Answer (score 2):

Add a `console.log("onTabChange in parent")` in `onTabChange` in your parent component.

Your should see it been called **before** your `console.log(focusableElements[0])`, and not again, not after.

For 2 reasons :

- You put `setFocusableElements(messageInput)` in a `useEffect`, because `ref.current` need to be rendered.
  But it will be called after the `onTabChange` which triggered the all thing in the first place.
- The `useEffect` will call `setFocusableElements` which will trigger a re-render of the childElement.
  The `useImperativeHandle` will be updated on this re-render with the `FocusableElements`,
  but changing `useImperativeHandle` **will not** trigger a re-render of the parent using the ref.

---

#### Solution :

The `focus()` should be place in a `useEffect`.

But then again, if you place this call in the parent, it will not work.
A child re-render will not trigger is parent re-render.
Best if you place directly the focus on the child.

We don't have the context here about why you build that this way, but if you absolutely need the focus to be controlled by the parent, use a boolean props instead :

```
// In the parent component :
const parent = () => {
   const [willFocus, setWillFocus] = useState(false);
   const onTabChange = activeKey => {
      if (activeKey === 1 && chatThreadRef.current) {
        setWillFocus(true)
      }
   }
   return <Child willFocus={willFocus} />
```

```
// In the child component :
const parent = ({willFocus}) => {
   const ref = useRef(null);
   useEffect(() => {
      willFocus && ref.current.focus();
   }, [willFocus]);

   return <input ref={ref} />
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there might be a small mistake in your code. Instead of setting the value property of the focusableElements[0] input element to '1' before calling focus(), you should set it after calling focus().

Try changing your focusInput function in the child component to:

```
focusInput: () => {
  console.log(focusableElements[0])
  focusableElements[0].focus()
  focusableElements[0].value = '1'
},
```

This way, the input element will be focused first and then its value will be set to '1'.